# Trying to output from Javascript file to HTML page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to output from a Javascript file to the HTML page, and I am coming across some difficulty.  Basically the user would select the options from the drop down menus and input from the text boxes, hit calculate and the program would calculate the necessary values.

After the calculation is complete there are three variables that I would like to output back to the page.  Disregard the actual calculations, they are irrelevant.  I am using jQuery and Javascript, I guess I can return a single variable but how do I return all of the variables I need.

Here is the HTML page I have and the javascript file.

```
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
      <title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="framework.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    function ShowCalculation() {
        Main($("#orangeSel").val(), $("#appleSel").val(), $("#soccerTxt").val(), $("#basketballTxt").val(), $("#banSel").val());

    }
</script>



    </head>
    <body>


    <div>

    <div>

    <br /> 
    <table border="0"> 
    <tr> 
    <td> 
    Number of Bananas
    </td> 
    <td> 
    <select id="banSel">

    <option value="1">1</option>

    <option value="2">2</option>

    <option value="3">3</option>

    <option value="4">4</option>

    </select> 
    </td> 
    <td> 
    Number of Oranges:
    </td> 
    <td><select id="orangeSel">

    <option value="1">1</option>

    <option value="2">2</option>

    <option value="3">3</option>

    <option value="4">4</option>

    </select>

    </td> 
    <td> 
    Apples
    </td> 
    <td> 
    <select id="appleSel">

    <option value="1">1</option>

    <option value="2">2</option>

    <option value="3">3 </option>

    <option value="4">4</option>

    </select> 
    </td> 
    </tr> 

    <tr> 
    <td> 
    Soccer Score:
    </td> 
    <td> 
    <input type="text" id="soccerTxt" value="2" size="3" /> 
    </td> 
    <td> 
    Basketball Score:
    </td> 
    <td> 
    <input type="text" id="basketballTxt" value="30" size="3" /> 
    </td> 
    </tr> 
    </table> 

    <br /> 
    <br /> 


<center><input type="submit" value="Calculate" onclick="ShowCalculation(); return false;" /></center>

    </div>
    </div>
    <div>
    <b><h1>Output</h1></b>
    <table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td>
    Manipulated Oranges:
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>
    Manipulated Apples:
    </td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Manipulated Soccer:</td>
    </tr>



    </table>

    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is the Javascript file

```
function Main(orange, apple, soccer, basketball, banana) {

var a = parseInt(orange);
var b = parseInt(apple);
var c = parseInt(soccer);
var d = 0;
var e = parseInt(basketball);
var f = parseInt(banana);


for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {

    d += c;

}

for (var j = 0; j < 10; i++) {

    c += 30;

}

var outputOne = c;
var outputTwo = d;
var outputThree = 5;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return several values from a JavaScript function you can create a new "anonymous" object, something like this in the Main() function:

```
function Main(orange, apple, soccer, basketball, banana) {
    var a = parseInt(orange);
    var b = parseInt(apple);
    var c = parseInt(soccer);
    var d = 0;
    var e = parseInt(basketball);
    var f = parseInt(banana);


    for (var i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        d += c;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < 10; i++) {
        c += 30;
    }

    var outputOne = c;
    var outputTwo = d;
    var outputThree = 5;

    return {output1:outputOne, output2:outputTwo, output3:outputThree};
}
```

Then you have to modify the markup to add ids to the fields where you want to output the variables:

```
<td>
Manipulated Oranges: <span  id="manOranges"></span>
</td>
```

Then you will have to change the JavaScript function ShowCalculation to look like this:

```
function ShowCalculation() {
    var results = Main($("#orangeSel").val(), $("#appleSel").val(), $("#soccerTxt").val(), $("#basketballTxt").val(), $("#banSel").val());

    $("#manOranges").html(results.output1);

}
```

...
Hope this helps

Edit: Added the complete Main function to show how the entire function has to look.

Comment: Let me try this I think this will work I tried something similar to this earlier.

Comment: A thing to note is that if you want to perform the calculation more than once it's better to add a span with id after the "Manipulated Oranges:" text, and set the html of the span instead of appending values to the td.

Comment: Just edited the answer to do as I mention on my previous comment.

Comment: I get an error saying "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'Main' is undefined"

Comment: that means you aren't importing correctly the javascript file that contains the Main function. If you get that then you were getting the same error with the code you show in the question.

Comment: I do not.  In my original code it transfers correctly to Javascript, but the problem and question I have is to output from the Javascript file to the HTML page?

Comment: Your entire Main() functions should look like the one in my answer (just edited it).

Comment: Forgot a "}".  FML!!  Sorry man.  Thanks for the help your answer works!

Answer (score 1):

You could return the results as an object. Something along these lines:

```
return {
    outputOne: c,
    outputTwo: d,
    outputThree: 5
};
```

This is know as JavaScript Object Literal Notation. You can read more about it in this [article](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/survey.html).

**EDIT:**

Using jQuery there are several ways you can then add the results to your page using. [jQuery.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [jQuery.html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) are two such ways.

I posted an example using your code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DZtZV/). Also, there is a bug in this line:

```
for (var j = 0; j < 10; i++)
```

`i++` should be `j++`.

Comment: how do I then output this in my HTML page.?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are using the id selector to get the value of some elements

`$("#orangeSel").val()`

In the same way, you need to set the value once you do the computation

`$("#answer-area").html('the answer)`

I *believe* if your answer-area is an input, you can use `val('the answer')` in place of `html`.

Comment: i'm confused? Is that how I write the answer?  I have to return many variables.

Comment: @spets, im just saying, take the results and use jquery to write the values into the doc.  If your question is how to return the values,  do so in an object literal like {output1: outputOne, output2: outputTwo...}.

Answer (score 0):

f you want to return the value to another javascript function you could use an map object:

```
var output=[ val1, val2, val3];
```

and then loop trough em with a foreach

```
for (i in output){
  do something
}
```

if you want to display these values in your html i would advice you to set the values from your javascript directly by giving the cell you want the values at an ID and putting a value like this

```
document.getElementById('answer1').innerHTML = val1;
```